# How can I update a record in yii cgridview like phpmyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, yii, phpmyadmin

I have a CGridView un yii, but I want to update the records like phpmyadmin (click or double click in the cell the when hit enter update in the database)

i.e

```
| id | name  | fk_id
+----+-------+-------
| 1  | name1 | 10
+----+-------+-------
| 2  | name2 | 12
+----+-------+-------
| 3  | name3 | 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGridView is not editable by default, you can just Use this [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/editablegridview) and save yourself from re-inventing the wheel.